# What is $('#container')[0]?

Tags: jquery

I don't understand the line on page 111 of the jQuery Cookbook, where it says:

```
$('#container')[0].innerHTML = html.join('');
```

What is the [0] about?
It's giving me a syntax error.

Comment: you have to use the [0] because the $('#container') is retrieving an array of elements and with [0] you access the first, if you remove it you will select all the element which fall the selector condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery method actually returns an array.  When you use the indexer, you get the actual DOM element at that position.  Unfortunately, if there is no matching element the indexer will fail.  Your selector probably doesn't match any id on the page.

The canonical way to do this would actually be:

```
$('#container').html( html.join('') ); // assuming html is an array
```

Note that this won't fail if there isn't a matching element on the page; the `html` method will simply not be applied.

Comment: D'oh!  Oh, well, THAT would help!

Comment: If you are referring to `$()` (which is not a method btw), it does not return an array. It returns a jQuery instance object.

Comment: Interesting, any idea why the OP got a syntax error, instead of something like `$('#container')[0] is undefined` ?

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is probably incorrect, vote for another one!**

It's probably trying to grab the first element with id `container`.  Try it like this:

```
$('#container:first').innerHTML = html.join('');
```

Comment: That won't work as there isn't an `innerHtml` property on the jQuery object.  It probably ought to be `$('#container').html( html.join('') );` There really ought to be only one element on the page with that id if there are any.

Comment: nope, [0] is used to address the DOM element inside the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

It references the first element in the array, which would be the DOMElement of #container, and it directly sets the `innerHTML` property of it to be the result of the join of `html` variable.

The left hand seems syntactically fine. Try replacing `html.join` with just a string literal and it should assign properly. Debug the `html.join` part.